# Does this "overly general" type of programming have a name?

Tags: multi-tenant, paradigms

Anyone who has experience with the Salesforce platform will know it can essentially be used as a backend for a lot of web applications. They let the end user define custom objects and the fields on those objects. So for instance, rather than having some entity as a strongly-typed class in the code, they have a generic "custom object", whose behaviour and data is defined by the fields you choose and the triggers and rules you apply to it. So they don't have to update the code, recompile and redeploy every time a user adds one (which, given they are a web service would be both impractical and cause serious downtime, *a lot*).

I was thinking how this could be implemented, and I think Salesforce may do it in a very complex way but I'm specifically thinking how *I* can implement this. So far I've come up with this:

- An "object defintion", which contains all the metadata for a specific record type. Equivalent to a hardcoded class definition.
- A generic "record", probably with some sort of dictionary/map tying values to field identifiers that exist in the object definition.
- When operating on user data, both the record and the object defintion need to be in memory so that the integrity of the data can be checked. Behaviour normally provided by methods can be applied using some kind of trigger system (again, I'm using a Salesforce example here because it's the best example I know of) with defined actions/events.

This whole system seems very clunky, slow (without serious optimisation), and like it would be prone to problems which wouldn't plague 99% of software projects, so I'd like to learn more about it, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Is the idea I've laid out above already an existing paradigm and if so what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered the custom-fields. The design is to enable tenant specific fields against a fixed entity. Since multi-tenancy at the highest level demand That a single codebase / database be used for all tenants with the options to full Customization. This design is the best approach. The below link points to a patent That was granted for managing the custom-fields per tenant.

https://www.google.com/patents/US7779039